# Android GC output HTC One

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I've recenently purchased a HTC One and started developping a Java App. Before that I had a Galaxy S II. On the Galaxy phone the GC output was always printed to the log. Something like:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 450K ...
```

But on the new HTC One these messages are nowehre to be found. I have searched a bit on Google and here but have not found a solution. Is there a way to turn them on, or get other good gc statistics?

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure that you wan't to came back GC_CONCURRENT messages. I'm asking because it's appears only when heap is full.

Comment: Yes I want to see them, because I want to know when exactly garbage collection happens and especially how much time the GC takes. I know that garbage collection happens on the HTC One but it somehow just doesn't get logged.

Comment: Have you find a solution or an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

`GC_CONCURRENT` Triggered when the heap is growing. So it can reclaim memory in time so the heap doesn't need to be enlarged

Check that you have same version of android on your devices.

For checking `memory leaks` in your app you can use:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html

Also you can try to simulate memory leak, and try to catch `GC_CONCURRENT` it should be in log.

Comment: The Galaxy S II is on 4.1.2 and the HTC One on 4.2.2, so no major change. I don't need to simulate a memory leak, when I run the App on the Galaxy S II I see GC messages about every 5 seconds (It's a game and causes quite some garbage :). But on the HTC One I see none.

Comment: @user2408857 you can simulate memory leaks, to check that it can be captured on HTC One. Also there can be difference in realization of working with memory on devices producted by different companies (HTC and Samsung)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure since it seems both your devices are on Jellybean 4.1 vs 4.2, but have a look at [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28857/how-can-i-access-android-log-files-on-my-nexus-7-without-root-access).

Google seems to have removed the ability to view system logs starting with JellyBean. It could be that Samsung decided not to do this with their 4.1 for the GS2. Regardless, you now require root in order to view full logs on your device.

Since you do not specify **how** you are viewing logs, I am assuming you mean on the device, using an app or terminal. However, you can view the full logs using ADB (with `adb logcat`) on a computer with the device connected.